# TFS - Create chart with all check in by day

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, charts, azure-devops

I want to make a chart with all Check In in days in my TFS.

I'm using Visual Studio online and I make the next query

In my taks I can see the changeset in LINKS tab but I only see the column "Related Count Item" but this only show the numbers of tasks asociate to my backlogs. I don't know how to get the changeset count.

[image: Changeset in my task]

I want to have a chart like this but showing the numbers of check ins in a day. This are showing the number of related task added every day.

[image]

Comment: You're not going to be able to generate a chart for that in VSO. With on-prem TFS you could write a report against the data warehouse. Why are you interested in knowing this number? It seems meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet available in VSO. You would need to get the data from the API and build the chart yourself. The data should be available in the rest API, and in the object model.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview